# If statements givng parser errors no matter what

Tags: error, parser

Below ive attached a very simple picture of some code that is reciving the same error as my actual code. Ive just made a super simple example for ease.

[image]

And here is the error im getting.

[image]

Any ideas on what's causing this to happen?
I get this error on every 'IF' statment I write.

Comment: Please add your own code and try to avoid posting a picture instead of the code.

Answer (score 0):

If statments must be inside of a function if you want to avoid errors.